# Optimising Typescript (or JavaScript) functions / methods to reduce repitition when using Observables

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have a TypeScript service to determine between members of an app and gold members. In my service / class I have two methods:

```
public getMembers():Observable<MembersListings> {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
            .map((response:Response) => response.json())
            .publishReplay(1)
            .refCount();
    }

public getPremiumMembers():Observable<MembersListings> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
        .map((response:Response) => this.formatListings(response.json()))
        .publishReplay(1)
        .refCount();
}

public formatListings(jsonObj:any):any {
    // do something
    return jsobObj;
}
```

However looking at it, i could just call / use the first method, `this.getMembers()` in the second method `this.getPremiumMembers()` It would make things a little cleaner as they both do the same thing, I just use a formatting function in the second method otherwise they are identical. However when I try to replace `this.http.get(this.url)`with `this.getMembers()`in the second method I get a horrible error. How could I achieve what I want correctly? Sorry for such a silly question but I am new to TS / RxJS.

Comment: it might depend on how the getPremiumMembers method is called. It might be that 'this' might not point to the object anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only difference between `getMembers()` and `getPremiumMembers()` is that `getPremiumMembers()` has to do some side effect (formatListings). If it's the case, I would suggest merging them:

```
public getMembers(premium: boolean):Observable<MembersListings> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
        .map((response:Response) => response.json())
        .do(premium ? this.formatListings.bind(this) : void 0)
        .publishReplay(1)
        .refCount();
}
```

If your `do something` in formatListings modifies jsonObj before returning it, replace  `.do(premium ? this.formatListings.bind(this) : void 0)` with `.map(json => (premium ? this.formatListings(json) : json))`

Answer (score 0):

You can update your get request to take a more generic formatter:

```
public getMembers(isPremium: boolean):Observable<MembersListings> {

    return this.http.get(this.url)
        .map((response:Response) => this.formatListings(response.json(), isPremium))
        .publishReplay(1)
        .refCount();
}
```

Which will only manipulate the json if they are a premium member:

```
private formatListings(jsonObj:any, isPremium: boolean):any {

    if (!isPremium) {
        // not a premium member, return it;
        return jsonObj;
    }

    // do stuff to manipulate premium members
    return jsobObj;
}
```